# Beginner with 'nextLine'

Tags: java

I am working on a java problem at the moment where I am creating a program that simulates the old TV quiz show, *You Bet Your Life*. The game show host, Groucho Marx, chooses a secret word, then chats with the contestants for a while. If either contestant uses the secret word in a sentence, he or she wins $100.00.

My program is meant to check for this secret word.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Groucho {
  String secret; 

  Groucho(String secret) {
     this.secret = secret; 
  }

  public String saysSecret(String line) {
     if(secret.equals(line)){
         return ("true");
     } else {
         return ("false");
     }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
  }

}
```

In the main method I need to now create a new `Groucho` object with a `secret` word from the first line of standard input (`in.nextLine()`).

I am not sure how I go about doing this? Can someone explain please! 
Thanks! 
Miles

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline

Comment: Scanner Detailed explanation http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and perhaps the [Java Tutorial on Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html). And that on [Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

Learning the basics is usually more useful than just getting a line of code from somewhere.

No offence :).

Comment: +1 for `Learning the basics is usually more useful than just getting a line of code from somewhere.`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the line with the following statement:

```
String line = in.nextLine();
```

Then, if you'd like to have the first word (for example),  you can split the line and create a new Groucho object.

```
String split = line.split(" ");
Groucho g = new Groucho(split[0]);
```

Here you can find more information about :

- [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
- [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: When I try that is says:
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method readLine()

Comment: Don't you have to declare `split` as a `String []`, not just a `String`?

Comment: It has to be a `String[]`, because the `.split()` method returns an array of `String` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a new `Groucho` object and pass in `in.nextLine()` as a parameter.  This would be done by `Groucho g = new Groucho( in.nextLine() );`

Answer (score 0):

You will need something that looks like this:

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //take in word

String secretWord = in.nextLine(); //put it in a string

Groucho host = new Groucho (secretWord); //create a Groucho object and pass it the word

Answer (score 0):

in.nextLine() will take a single line of the whole input, so you can simply pass it into the constructor.

For example:

```
String inputWord = in.nextLine();
Groucho g = new Groucho(inputWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Scanner` class the `nextLine()` method takes the next line of input as a `String`. You can save that line of input to a `String` variable:

```
String line = in.nextLine();
```

Now that you have a full line of input, you can get the first word from it.

In a sentence each word is separated from other words by a space. In the `String` class the `split()` method can split a `String` into an array of smaller strings, such as words in a sentence, with a given separator, such as a space (" "), that you specify as a parameter:

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

Next you can choose a secret word from the array by selecting the appropriate index.

For the first word:

```
String chosenWord = words[1];
```

For the last word:

```
String chosenWord = words[words.length - 1];
```

For a random word:

```
String chosenWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
```

Now you can simply pass on the secret word as a parameter to a new `Groucho` constructor:

```
Groucho secretWord = new Groucho(chosenWord);
```

This step by step explanation created a new variable at each step. You can accomplish the same task by combining multiple lines of code into a single statement and avoid creating unnecessary variables.