# Why does this code not end?

Tags: java, loops

```
class Operation {
double add(double a, double b){
    double c;
    c = a+b;
    return c;
}
double sub(double a, double b){

    double c;
    c = a-b;
    return c;
}
double mul(double a, double b){
    double c;
    c = a*b;
    return c;
}
double div(double a, double b){
    double c;
    c = a/b;
    return c;
}
}

class Selection{    
static double x,y;
void sel(int a){
    Operation op = new Operation();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char b;
    if(a==1)
        b='+';
    else if(a==2)
        b='-';
    else if(a==3)
        b='*';
    else
        b='/';
    System.out.println(">>You have selected "+b+" operator");
    System.out.println(">>Please enter the first operand.");
    x = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(">>Please enter the second operand.");
    y = sc.nextDouble();
    }
double x(){
    return x;
}
double y(){
    return y;
}
}


public class Calculator {
static int select;

public static void main(String [] args){
    Operation op = new Operation();
    Selection se = new Selection();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean run = true;


    while(run){
        System.out.printf(">>Select Operator\n>>1: +  2: -  3: *  4: /\n");
        select = sc.nextInt();

        if(select == 1){
            se.sel(1);
            double a = se.x();
            double b = se.y();
            double result = op.add(a, b);
            System.out.println(">>The result of "+a+" + "+b+" is "+result);

        }else if (select ==2){
            se.sel(2);
            double a = se.x();
            double b = se.y();
            double result = op.sub(a,b);
            System.out.println(">>The result of "+a+" - "+b+" is "+result);

        }else if (select ==3){
            se.sel(3);
            double a = se.x();
            double b = se.y();
            double result = op.mul(a,b);
            System.out.println(">>The result of "+a+" * "+b+" is "+result);

        }else if(select == 4){
            se.sel(4);
            double a = se.x();
            double b = se.y();
            double result = op.div(a,b);
            System.out.println(">>The result of "+a+" / "+b+" is "+result);

        }else {
            System.out.println(">>Your number is not available, please try again!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        }       


        System.out.println(">>Do you want to exit the program(y/n)?");
        String startOver = sc.nextLine();

        if(startOver.equals("y")){
            run = false;
            System.out.println(">>Thank you for using my program!");
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }
}

}
```

So this is my calculation program for a high school homework. It works fine until, asking for quitting the program or keep continuing the code. Even if I want to quit the program, it restarts after showing the results. I think there's something wrong at the end of the code. Can somebody help?

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5032408/875832 ? It looks like it's possible that it's always hitting the `else`, because there's a remaining newline from the previous input. I recommend you examine the contents of `startOver`.

Comment: Try debugging exactly what `startOver` gets when the user enters "y". I would wager that it contains "y" plus a newline character, which causes the `.equals("y")` check to fail.

Comment: @jbabey it was confusing as hell, but i finally figured out the problem. I changed 'sc.nextLine();' to 'sc.next();' and it works like magic.  Like you said, i think that "Line" added a newline character. Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
String startOver = sc.nextLine();
```

When you read in the operand numbers with `nextDouble()`, the method leaves rest of the line in the parser/buffer.

So when you call `nextLine()` you are still reading the rest of the previous line.
This will cause your `startOver` string to be empty and the `if` condition doesn't work as well.

I suggest you to use `scan.next()` instead of `scan.nextLine()`

Comment: Yeah, i changed it and it worked. I've got to study more about the differences! thanks!