# Java why wont scanner work inside a switch

Tags: java, input, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner asking for some preferences. It creates an `int` variable `choice` between 0 and 3. Then I do the following:

```
String location;
switch(choice){
    case 0:
        System.out.println("Please type the zip codes you would like to search in a comma separated list");
        location = input.nextLine();
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Please type the street names you would like to search in a comma separated list");
        location = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Please type the boroughs you would like to search in a comma separated list");
        location = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        break;
    default:
        location = "none";
        break;
    }
String locations[] = location.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

now to me this seems perfectly fine, but when choice is set to 0,1, or 2 it will print the correct line, but skip the part where the user has to input something (the line that looks like location=...)

this means that it does not give the user the chance to enter anything and therefore `locations` becomes a blank list. **Why does this happen and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Check out this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably reading the newline after the last input, instead of the really next line. Try:

```
int choice = input.nextInt();

input.nextLine(); // <--- Eat it here!
String location;
switch(choice){
    case 0:
        Syst...
```

The `nextInt()` call, where you prompt the choice, does not end the line. So the first call to `nextLine()` after `nextInt()` is going to return an empty String. To fix that, eat the empty line after the integer and then move on.

Comment: What about using new Scanner for this input?

Comment: @nazar_art: Totally offtopic and most likely wrong, or I didn't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: this was my issue...thanks! I will except your answer in 6 minutes when I am permitted to

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux I wondering to know whether possibly to use new scanner for input, after `int choice = input.nextInt();` is executed?

Comment: Well, that is wrong because of so many reasons. 1) You are creating unnecessary objects. 2) This might fail, if the underlying inputstream is wrapped within a BufferedInput stream that comes from a File. 3) The OP his problem is well defined behavior of a Scanner and should simply be handled as desired. 4) It is just ugly to create a new Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you. Try:

```
case 'f' :
                System.out.println("Enter a word or phrase to be found:");
                scnr.nextLine();
                String phrase = scnr.nextLine(); //
```

Answer (score 0):

Put nextLine after the read before the switch.

```
System.out.print("Digite um número ente 1 e 9: ");
int opc = read.nextInt();
read.nextLine();
switch(opc) {
```

And read your value  with nextLine()

```
case 6:
    String[] procurados = read.nextLine().split(" ");
```