# NZEC runtime error on SPOJ

Tags: java, runtime-error, postfix-notation

My code is running successfully on ideone but is showing NZEC runtime error on SPOJ. Can someone please explain what is wrong with my code?

```
import java.util.*;
class tuna{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();
        String[] str = new String[100];
        String pri = "+-*/^";

        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
           str[i]=in.nextLine();
        }

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<str[i].length(); j++){
            char ch = str[i].charAt(j);
            if(Character.isLetter(ch))
                System.out.print(ch);
            else if(ch == '('){
                stack.push("(");
            }
            else if(ch == ')' )
            {
                while(!stack.isEmpty() && stack.lastElement()!="("){
                    System.out.print(stack.pop());

                }
                stack.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                while(!stack.empty() && stack.lastElement()!="(" && pri.indexOf(ch)<= pri.indexOf(stack.lastElement()))
                {
                    System.out.print(stack.pop());
                }
                stack.push(Character.toString(ch));
            }
        }
        while(!stack.isEmpty())
        {

            stack.pop();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    in.close();

  }
}
```

would be grateful for some insight on NZEC error. Thank you.
test cases(as given on spoj) :

```
Input:
3
(a+(b*c))
((a+b)*(z+x))
((a+t)*((b+(a+c))^(c+d)))

Output:
abc*+
ab+zx+*
at+bac++cd+^*
```

Comment: please put up the question/test cases

Comment: You're asking for `nextLine()` ***how many times through*** in the first loop?  Why would this *not* freeze up on an automated tester?  It has to both enter in however much data it's specified it would enter in, enter it in, *and* intuitively know *when* to enter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking from your code. Mistake is using `in.nextLine()` . Check [Using scanner.nextLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline) .

Correction : change to `in.next()`

```
 for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
     str[i]=in.next();
 }
```

And I really suggest you to use `BufferedReader` instead of Scanner for SPOJ questions for better performance