# Java string comparison with object string

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have an object which I import in another object

First object:

```
package test;
import java.util.*;

public class Eveniment {
    int ziua;
    String luna = new String();

    public void setZiua(int param){
        ziua = param;
    }
    public void setLuna(String param){
        luna = param;
    }
    public int getZiua(){
        return ziua; 
    }
    public String getLuna(){
        return luna;
    }
}
```

Second object:

```
package test;
import test.*;
import java.util.*;
public class EventPlanner {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Eveniment> myAr = new ArrayList();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduceti ziua urmata de luna evenimentului: ");

        int zi = 0;
        String luna;
        zi = sc.nextInt();
        luna = sc.nextLine();

        Eveniment first = new Eveniment();
        first.setZiua(zi);
        first.setLuna(luna);

        myAr.add(first);

        while(luna!=null && zi!=0)
        {
            zi = sc.nextInt();
            luna = sc.nextLine();

            if(zi!=0)
            {
                Eveniment ev = new Eveniment();
                ev.setZiua(zi);
                ev.setLuna(luna);

                myAr.add(ev);
            }

        }

        String l = new String();
        l = "Ianuarie";

        System.out.println(myAr.size());*/

        for(int i = 0; i < myAr.size(); i++){
            if(myAr.get(i).getLuna().equals(l))
                System.out.println(1);
            else
                System.out.println(0);
        }
    }

    public static void afisare(ArrayList<Eveniment> myAr){
        System.out.println("---------Array------------");
        for(Eveniment i : myAr){
            System.out.println(i.getLuna() +" "+i.getZiua());
        }
    }
}
```

The thing that bugs me is that inside the `for` I do a check if a current object has it's `luna` string equal to `l` string then I print out 1 else I print 0, but the algorithm prints out 0 even if the strings are equal, what am I doing wrong ?
I'm a newbie with Java so please don't judge too harshly.

Input given to the program:

```
1 Decembrie
2 Ianuarie
3 Februarie
4 Martie
0//to end the input
```

The program should write

```
`Decembrie` 0
`Ianuarie` 1
`Februarie` 0
`Martie` 0
```

because `l` is equal to `Ianuarie`.

Comment: Exactly what is the input being given to the program?

Comment: what's the input that you pass?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline is probably worth a read

Comment: Also, you could iterate through the list with: `for (String str : myAr)`.

Comment: alright, I provided an example input for the program.

Comment: I managed to solve it thanks to @RC. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because

```
l = "Ianuarie"
```

and

```
 myAr.get(i).getLuna() =" Ianuarie"
                        ^--->there are space before the Ianuarie
```

so you will never get `1`

Comment: Just change to: `luna = sc.nextLine().trim();`