# Why is hasNext() False, but hasNextLine() is True?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

### Question

How is it that for a scanner object the `hasNextLine()` method returns true  while the `hasNext()` method returns false?

Note: Based on the input file, the `hasNext()` method is returning the result as expected; the `hasNextLine()` does not seem to be returning the correct result.

### Code

Here's the code I'm running that's creating the results below:

```
public void ScannerTest(Reader fileReaderObject){
    Scanner scannerObj = new Scanner(fileReaderObject);

    for(int i = 1; scannerObj.hasNext(); i++){
        System.out.println(i + ": " + scannerObj.next());
        System.out.println("Has next line: " + scannerObj.hasNextLine());
        System.out.println("Has next: " + scannerObj.hasNext());
    }
    System.out.println();

    scannerObj.close();
}
```

### Input File

The following is the actual content of the file that I'm passing to this scanner:

```
a   3   9
b   3   6
c   3   3
d   2   8
e   2   5
f   2   2
g   1   7
h   1   4
i   1   1
```

### Result

The following is the end of what's printed in the console when I run my code, and includes the portion I can't make sense of:

```
25: i
Has next line: true
Has next: true
26: 1
Has next line: true
Has next: true
27: 1
Has next line: true
Has next: false
```

Comment: Is there an empty line at the end of your input file by chance?

Comment: `hasNextLine()` returns true if there is a next line, even empty. `hasNext()` returns true if there is one more token. An empty line is a line, which doesn't contain any token.

Comment: I think `next` doesn't consume the `\n`, so the "cursor" is right before the newline, thus there is a next line, but there's no more token.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The file does not include a blank line following "i   1 1", so I would expect that once it moves the 2nd "1" on the last line, there is not another line or return character for it to pick up.

Interestingly though, if I use the nextLine() method after the loop, I do not get an error.  So maybe there is a return character hanging out there?

Any thoughts on how I can get the results of the hasNextLine() method and the hasNext() method to align?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

#### You have a single extra newline at the end of your file.

- [`hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) checks to see if there is another `linePattern` in the buffer.
- [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) checks to see if there is a parseable token in the buffer, as separated by the scanner's delimiter.

Since the scanner's delimiter is whitespace, and the `linePattern` is also white space, it is possible for there to be a `linePattern` in the buffer but no parseable tokens.

Typically, the most common way to deal with this issue by always calling `nextLine()` after parsing all the tokens (e.g. numbers) in each line of your text. You need to do this when using `Scanner` when reading a user's input too from `System.in`. To advance the scanner past this whitespace delimiter, you must use `scanner.nextLine()` to clear the line delimiter. See: [Using scanner.nextLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5032356/1768232)

---

**Appendix:**

`LinePattern` is defined to be a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that matches this:

```
private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN =
                                       "\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]";
private static final String LINE_PATTERN = ".*("+LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN+")|.+$";
```

The default token delimiter is this `Pattern`:

```
private static Pattern WHITESPACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
                                            "\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the detailed response.  So I understand that there might be a Line_Separator_Pattern without another token being present. However in the file I can't advance my cursor past the final "1".  Is there some whitespace character I can't delete through gedit?

Comment: `"You have a single extra newline at the end of your file."` - I think it's more general than that, as in - there is any amount of white-space (or whichever delimiter you specified) at the end of the file.

Comment: @Dukeling yes, but OP stated somewhere he checked his file and it didn't have extra white space

Answer (score 16):

The reason is that `hasNext()` checks if there are any more non-whitespace characters available. `hasNextLine()` checks to see if there is another line of text available. Your text file probably has a newline at the end of it so it has another line but no more characters that are not whitespace.

Many text editors automatically add a newline to the end of a file if there isn't one already.

In other words, your input file is not this (the numbers are line numbers):

```
1. a   3   9
2. b   3   6
3. c   3   3
4. d   2   8
5. e   2   5
```

It is actually this:

```
1. a   3   9
2. b   3   6
3. c   3   3
4. d   2   8
5. e   2   5
6.
```

Answer (score 14):

### Short answer

You have an empty line at the end of the file.

---

### Reason for the empty line

If you take your content and save it for example into a txt file, some editors will add an empty new line to your file.

The editors behave this way, because this is part of the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) standard:

> **3.206 Line**
>
> A sequence of zero or more non-  characters plus a terminating  character.

This topic has been discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-files-end-with-a-newline).

---

### Java Scanner documentation

Here is the documentation from the [Java 8 Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

> **`hasNext()`**
>
> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.

---

> **`hasNextLine()`**
>
> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.

---

### Reason for the Java code behavior

Because of the above described facts, `hasNextLine()` will return `true`, but `hasNext()` cannot find anything, which it can recognize as `Token` and returns therefore `false`.

For additional infos see [durron597](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31993534/1943228) post.

Answer (score 5):

You are consuming the value of `next()`, but asking for `hasNext()` and `hasNextLine()`. `next()`, per default, returns everything to the next `whitespace()`. So you are iterating through all whitespace seperated strings, and after each of them you are asking about the `nextLine()`.

`i   1   1` -> `hasNextLine()`? True. `hasNext()`? Also true.

`1   1` -> `hasNextLine()`? True. `hasNext()`? Also true (still a whitespace left)

`1` -> `hasNextLine()`? True (Line Seperator, probably). haxNext? False, no whitespace anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The Basic concept of hasNext() and hasNextLine() is

**hasNextLine**:-
**Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.**
This method may block while waiting for input. The scanner does not advance past any input.

**Returns:**
true if and only if this scanner has another line of input
Throws:
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

**hasNext**

**Returns true if the next complete token matches the specified pattern.**

A complete token is prefixed and postfixed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input. The scanner does not advance past any input.

**Parameters:**
pattern - the pattern to scan for

**Returns:**
true if and only if this scanner has another token matching the specified pattern

Since your last input saying true for nextLine() because A call to scan.nextLine(); returns the next token. It's important to note that **the scanner returns a space and a letter, because it's reading from the end of the last token until the beginning of the next line.**