# Why do I get an error on hasNextLine, but not on hasNext?

Tags: java

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
out.println(9);
}

out.close();

while (s.hasNextLine()) {
  int i = s.nextInt();
  if ( i == 9);
  {
  System.out.print("*");
  }
} 

s.close();
```

It still prints out 10 "*", but i get this error afterward:

```
**********java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at insertionSort.main(insertionSort.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

But if I use hasNext instead of hasNextLine, it works fine.

So I am wondering why hasNext works, but hasNextLine doesn't.

Comment: What is the variable `s`?

Comment: s is the scanner that scan the file

Answer (score 1):

> - [`hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine())
>     checks to see if there is another `linePattern` in the buffer.
> - [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext())
>     checks to see if there is a parseable token in the buffer, as
>     separated by the scanner's delimiter.
>
> Since the scanner's delimiter is whitespace, and the linePattern is
>   also white space, it is possible for there to be a linePattern in the
>   buffer but no parseable tokens.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31993534/5333805

So your file could have an empty newline so you try to read a character which isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for nextInt before trying to get it:

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
  if(s.hasNextInt()){
    int i = s.nextInt();
    if ( i == 9);
    {
      System.out.print("*");
    }
  }
}
```