# The output file value is null (0KB)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader, filewriter

I'm trying to write file using using file writer but the value is null :

```
  FileReader inCorpus2=new FileReader("output2.txt");
       FileWriter outCorpus2=new FileWriter("Doc2(THE WANTED FILE).txt");
       Scanner sc2=new Scanner(inCorpus2);
       try{
           while(sc2.hasNextLine()){
               String tempLine=sc2.nextLine();
               Scanner sc3=new Scanner(tempLine);
       while(sc3.hasNext()){
           String temp=sc3.next();
           for(int i=0;i<UC.length;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<temp.length();j++){
                if(temp.charAt(j)==UC[i])temp=removeChar(temp,j);
               }
           }
```

And this is the error massage :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at aya.SecondFilePreproc.main(SecondFilePreproc.java:25)
```

I hope i was clear , i tried my best .. help me please .

Comment: You might solve your problem by using `hasNext()` instead of `hasNextLine()`. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31993534/4039840).

Comment: brief checked on the code and it runs fine.  You should provide a MCVE to demonstrate your problem

Comment: @TuyenNguyen the same code worked in another file ..

Comment: @AdrianShum Did it work fine ? . I know i'm beginner i'll try ..

Comment: @yousefaqra in case you dunno : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's help, need to see full code. Just added some exceptions.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public static String removeChar(String x,int y){
 return "something";
 }
public class SomeClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
       try(FileReader inCorpus2=new FileReader("output2.txt");
           FileWriter outCorpus2=new FileWriter("Doc2(THE WANTED FILE).txt");
           Scanner sc2=new Scanner(inCorpus2)
               ){
           while(sc2.hasNextLine()){
               String tempLine=sc2.nextLine();
               Scanner sc3=new Scanner(tempLine);
       while(sc3.hasNext()){
           String temp=sc3.next();    
           //just a guess what is UC
           //char UC[]={'A','B','C'};
       }
           for(int i=0;i<UC.length;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<temp.length();j++){
                if(temp.charAt(j)==UC[i])temp=removeChar(temp,j);
               }
            }
        } 
     }
   }
}
```