# java - reading two strings from the user

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the user to enter two strings and store them in two variables called `studentName` and `studentNum`, but when I run the program, the first string input is skipped over and only the second string input is allowed to be entered.
It prints out normally, but won't allow me to enter a value for `studentName`. could anyone help me with this problem?

`System.out.print("Please enter your name:  ");
studentName = in.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your student number:  ");
studentNum = in.nextLine();`

Comment: what is in.nextLine()? Where is the "in" class.

Comment: I believe 'in' is a Scanner

Comment: This was already answered here.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline

Comment: Oh yeah, in.nextLine() is my scanner class. I called it "in"...forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

Has to do with where the scanner starts and where it puts up a newline character

You can fix this if you change `System.out.print` to `System.out.println`