# How to read values till user presses enter in JAVA?

Tags: java, input, output, java.util.scanner

I need to take input in the form of-
Given 'n' number of boxes and each of these boxes may contain any number of distinct integers,
So first user enters n,then for each value of i from 1 to n,I need to enter values till enter is pressed.
I don't know how to do this,
Eg-

```
5
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2
1 
4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
```

I have tried this-

```
String str;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    while(true)
    {
       str=scanner.next();
       if(str.isEmpty())
          break;
       int val=Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}
```

Also tried str.equals("\n") and str.equals(""),
But nothing is working.
Somebody please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: You are only calling `scanner.next()` one time.  You need to call it in each iteration of your loop otherwise `str` will only ever have one value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline try scanner.readline - no need for customized checks

Comment: use str.equalsIgnoreCase("") instead of str.isEmpty()

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```java
int n = scanner.nextInt(); 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] array = str.split(" ");
}
```

You take a String from user (a single line of numbers) and you split it by space, so you have all the numbers as String in the array. Then you have to parse them to int or do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String str;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    while(true)
   {
   str=scanner.next();
   if(!str.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
      break;
   int val=Integer.parseInt(str);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scanner class has
 next(){only take input upto any white space character occur}
nextLine(){ takes input upto new line character }

Try with nextLine() method and then try to store in any array 
Using n value.Then you can use  split or string tokenzer function and then we extract integer from in it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```java
while (true) {
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("")) break;                        
}
```