# Cannot Input String

Tags: java

Trying to figure out why my String userString = ""; is not recognized.  All of my other variable types show up as a different color.

Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class BasicInput {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  int userInt = 0;
  double userDouble = 0.0;
  char userChar = 'a';
  String userString = "";

  System.out.println("Enter integer: ");
  userInt = scnr.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter double: ");
  userDouble = scnr.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("Enter character: ");
  userChar = scnr.next().charAt(0);

  System.out.println("Enter string: ");
  userString = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println(userInt + " " + userDouble + " " + userChar + " " + userString);

  return;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking about the difference between a class and a keyword?

Comment: this sounds like an issue with an IDE. If so, you should remove the 'java' tag and add the tag for the IDE, as this is not a java issue

Comment: Probably related or even duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline

Comment: "not recognized" by what?

Comment: What about `Scanner scnr`? Is it shown in a different color or does it behave like `String`? Maybe your editor only recognizes elementary data types but not objects.

Answer (score 0):

Runing the Code this is the output:

```
Enter integer: 
1
Enter double: 
22
Enter character: 
b
Enter string: 
1 22.0 b //Skips the userString = scnr.nextLine(); and jumps to the last println
```

For some reason when i run the program, using differents `.nextLine... .nextInt .next` it skips to read the last line, using just `.nextLine` and then using a method to check if the `String` is a `double` `integer` or `char` can resolve this