# error in the string msg output both comes together

Tags: java

my code is

```
import java.util.*;
public class Friends
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String f_name[]=new String[5];
        String l_name[]=new String[5];
        String l_concat[]=new String[5];
        int sr[]=new int[5];
        int i;
        System.out.print("\f");
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        System.out.print("Enter your Roll number: ");
        sr[i]=in.nextInt();          
        System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
        f_name[i]=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
        l_name[i]=in.nextLine();
        l_concat[i]=f_name[i].concat (l_name[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        System.out.println("sr "+i+" first name: "+l_name[i]+" last name: "+f_name[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

The both First name and last name output is comes together Please help me find the how could it come one by one first come first name msg and then last last name msg.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String f_name[] = new String[5];
    String l_name[] = new String[5];
    String l_concat[] = new String[5];
    int sr[] = new int[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter your Roll number: ");
        sr[i] = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        f_name[i] = in.next();

        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        l_name[i] = in.next();

        l_concat[i] = f_name[i].concat(l_name[i]);
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    in.close();

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("sr " + i + " first name: " + l_name[i] + " last name: " + f_name[i]);
    }
}
```

For more details, check this thread.
[Using scanner.nextLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline)

Comment: Thanks Avinash...............