# How to Take input String as Sentence after some input already taken

Tags: java, string, types, java.util.scanner

Sample Input:
    12,
    4.0,
    is good for Storing data!

Expected OutPut:
    16,
    8.0,
    String is good for Storing data!

Actual Output:
    16,
    8.0,
    String

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        String s = "string ";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i1;
        double d1;
        String s1;
        i1 = scan.nextInt();
        d1 = scan.nextDouble();
        s1 = scan.nextLine(); // if i am add this line before taking i1 is than its working fine but here not?

        System.out.println(i + i1);
        System.out.println(d + d1);
        System.out.println(s + " " + s1);
        scan.close();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo this will help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5032408/6583223 another helpful answer