# Not taking user input and jumping to else clause in a while loop

Tags: java

Im a beginner in JAVA and I have been trying to create a simple calculator program. I am facing a problem in the while loop where the loop does not wait for my input "ans" and directly jumps to the else clause

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scanner_program {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 1;
        while (i==1) 
        {   
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            int num = ob.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
            int num2 = ob.nextInt();
        
            System.out.println("Sum of "+num+" And "+num2+" is "+(num+num2));
            System.out.println("Remainder of "+num+" And "+num2+" is "+(num-num2));
            System.out.println("Product of "+num+" And "+num2+" is "+(num*num2));
            float answer= (float) num/num2;
            System.out.println("Quotient of "+num+" And "+num2+" is "+answer);
        
            System.out.print("Try Again? (Y/N) ");
            String ans = ob.nextLine();
        
            if (ans=="Y" || ans=="y" ) {
                // do nothing
            }
            else if (ans=="N" || ans=="n"){
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;
                }
            }   
    
        }
}
```

Comment: does your code working you are not updating `i` value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using scanner.nextLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline) Also, when naming your classes in Java, you should be CamelCase, so ScannerProgram

Answer (score 1):

`ob.nextLine()` is taking the newline character as its next value, so `ans` is set to an invalid character.

change `ob.nextLine()` to `ob.next()`.

Also, for Java, you should use `string.equals("another string")` so change your letter checking to this:

```
if (ans.equals("Y") || ans.equals("y") ) {
  // do nothing
}
else if (ans.equals("N") || ans.equals("n")){
  break;
}
```

Comment: Or you could write: `if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int num = ob.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
        int num2 = ob.nextInt();
    
        System.out.println("Sum of "+num+" And "+num2+" is "+(num+num2));
        System.out.println("Remainder of "+num+" And "+num2+" is "+(num-num2));
        System.out.println("Product of "+num+" And "+num2+" is "+(num*num2));
        float answer= (float) num/num2;
        System.out.println("Quotient of "+num+" And "+num2+" is "+answer);
    
        System.out.print("Try Again? (Y/N)");
        ob.nextLine();
        String ans = ob.nextLine();
    
        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            // do nothing
        } else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

You should enter ob.nextLine() to clear your input for other inputs you may enter.