# Strange behaviour of Scanner.nextFloat

Tags: java, localization, java.util.scanner

If I execute the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(64);
        String line = "1.1 2.2 3.3";
        float fsum = 0.0f;      

        s = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(" ");

        while (s.hasNextFloat()){
            float f = s.nextFloat();
            fsum += f;
            builder.append(f).append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("Floats found: " + builder);
        System.out.println("Sum: " + fsum);
        s.close();
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
Floats found: 
Sum: 0.0
```

But if I substitute the dots for commas in line `"1,1 2,2 3,3"`, then it does recognize the floats:

```
Floats found: 1.1 2.2 3.3 
Sum: 6.6000004
```

I guess it's because my SO is in Spanish, and we use commas instead of dots with decimal numbers. I thought of using Locale, but there isn't Locale.SPANISH.

Furthermore, it behaves just the opposite when I run this:

```
public class StringToFloatTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st = "1,1";
        float f = Float.parseFloat(st);
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

This code results in a `NumberFormatException`, but it works if I use `String st = "1.1"`.

Can somebody explain why this happens and how can I make the Scanner recognize the floats with dots?

Comment: Did you take a look at this post? It seems like it's related to the Locale of your system ( like you guess it ) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708219/weird-behaviour-with-scannernextfloat?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can somebody explain why this happens

As you said, it's using your default locale. Print `Locale.getDefault()` to check what your default locale is.

Note that [`Float.parseFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29) is *not* locale-specific.

> and how can I make the Scanner recognize the floats with dots?

Call `s.useLocale(Locale.US);`

Answer (score 0):

Java default locale choosing process is described in [Java 7 default locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107972/java-7-default-locale/11010758#11010758).

And here is how to change it externally without altering the source code in many places: 
[how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm)